# RichTextbox, RTF in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, rtf

I am using richtextbox in vb.net , which contains the value "секция", which is russian word.

`rtf1.selectedrtf` and `rtf.rtf`, it returns `/Un` representation of characters. Is there any way or option in `rtf` to return the value in `\uXXXX` format?.

```
секция='f1\'e5\'ea\'f6\'e8\'ff 
секция=\u0441\u0435\u043A\u0446\u0438\u044F (<-- i need this format)
=============================
rtf1.text=секция
rtf1.selectedrtf returns
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204{\*\fname Arial;}Arial CYR;}}  \uc1\pard\b\protect\f0\fs16\'f1\'e5\'ea\'f6\'e8\'ff}  "
```

Comment: You'll notice your RTF is using code page 204.  What you are asking for is the encoded Unicode bytes.  Two different beasts.  Find an ANSI Code Page to Unicode converter.  Or write one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a small function to convert a unicode string to unicode rtf text.

```
Private Function UnicodeStringToRtfText(str As String) As String
    Dim arrStr As Char() = str.ToCharArray()
    Dim retStr As String = ""
    For Each ch As String In arrStr
        If (AscW(ch) > 122) Then
            retStr &= "\u" & AscW(ch) & "?"
        Else
            retStr &= ch
        End If
    Next
    Return retStr
End Function
```

Hope this help!

Comment: `> 122` should be `> 126`, right? Those ASCII codes are 123 '{', 124 '|', 125 '}', and 126 '~'. See the [ASCII printable codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart). From my tests, they get added correctly to my RichTextBox. Also, surrogate pairs are not being handled, but maybe those are rare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Encoding class found in System.Text to get the format in utf 8.

Eg:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Text)
```

For more details you can look at the following link at msdn:

[Encoding.UTF8 Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx)
It has good coding examples that you can follow. I did not find anyway to set the encoding for a richtextbox but you can using the encoding class to get the format that you desire.